# Creating oracle for Grover's algorithm on Caesar cipher

Tags: qiskit, grovers-algorithm, cryptography

I am trying to replicate this oracle circuit[image: oracle circuit]

given [in this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/554#:%7E:text=Quantum%20computers%20can%20solve%20or,the%20key%20of%20symmetric%20cryptography.). I am trying to implement a Grover circuit that searches for the key for a known plaintext-ciphertext pair (P,C) = (0xF2,0x14). The oracle circuit for the problem is shown here. I have written a Qiskit code:

```
#Creating the MAJ gate

qr = QuantumRegister(3)
MAJ = QuantumCircuit(qr)
MAJ.cx(qr[2], qr[1])
MAJ.cx(qr[2], qr[0])
MAJ.mcx([qr[0], qr[1]], qr[2])
MAJ_gate = MAJ.to_gate()

#Creating UMA gate

qr1 = QuantumRegister(3)
UMA = QuantumCircuit(qr1)
UMA.mcx([qr1[0], qr1[1]], qr1[2])
UMA.cx(qr1[2], qr1[0])
UMA.cx(qr1[0], qr1[1])
UMA_gate = UMA.to_gate()

#Creating a n-qubit adder circuit

n = 9
qr = QuantumRegister(n)
adder_ckt = QuantumCircuit(qr)

#Appending MAJ gates

i = 0
while i+2 < n:
adder_ckt.append(MAJ_gate, ([qr[i] for i in range(i, i+3)]))
i = i+2

#Append the CNOT gate
#adder_ckt.cx(qr[n-2], qr[n-1])

#Appending the UMA gates
j = n
while j > 2:
adder_ckt.append(UMA_gate, ([qr[i] for i in range(j-3, j)]))
j = j-2


#Converting to gate
adder = adder_ckt.to_gate() 

#Create oracle gate

#Key length
k = 4

#Define Registers
q = QuantumRegister(3*k+1)

#Define the circuit
keyfinder = QuantumCircuit(q)

#Put keys into superposition
for i in range(1, 5):
    keyfinder.x(q[i])
    keyfinder.h(q[i])

#Modify qubits according to plaintext bits    
keyfinder.x(q[6])
keyfinder.x(q[i] for i in range(9, 13))

adder_list = []
for i in range(5):
    adder_list.append(i)
for i in range(9, 13):
    adder_list.append(i)


keyfinder.append(adder, [q[i] for i in range(0, 9)])
keyfinder.append(adder, adder_list)


#Middle part of the oracle
for i in range(5,7):
    keyfinder.x(q[i])
keyfinder.x(q[8])
for i in range(10, 13):
    keyfinder.x(q[i])

adder_list2 = [i for i in range(5,12)]

keyfinder.h(q[12])
keyfinder.mcx(adder_list2, q[12])
keyfinder.h(q[12])

for i in range(5,7):
    keyfinder.x(q[i])
keyfinder.x(q[8])
for i in range(10, 13):
    keyfinder.x(q[i])

#Append the adders again
keyfinder.append(adder, adder_list)
keyfinder.append(adder, [q[i] for i in range(0, 9)])
```

where the MAJ gate is
and the UMA gate is[image]
[image]

The adder is a quantum ripple-carry adder. The authors suggest to ignore the high-carry qubit and I have thus done so. My adder turns out to be[image]
while my oracle turns out to be[image]
Now the problem is after iterating the circuit 3 times, I am supposed to get 0010 after making measurements on the keys, but I am getting a wrong answer of 0000. I cannot find the mistake. I would really appreciate if someone helps me out.

Comment: Do you run the circuit on a QPU or a simulator? First, I would check on simulator.

Comment: @MartinVesely I ran the circuit through the QASM simulator. The circuit is supposed to return 0010 but it is returning 0000.